# set-install-location doesnt work

Tags: android, adb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i need to set my android to install apps on the external SD. So many tutorials,and on many of them i have found the set-install-location command.

I used it,and used get-install-location to see the actual install location,and appears to be correct (2[external]). But,wen i go to the phone and try to install something,he doesnt install and show the insuficient space message.

The android version is 4.0.3 and the phone its an LG Optimus L5

PS: sorry for some english wrong,im brazilian and not used to write in english (and no patience for google translate)

Answer (score -1):

Brother

The above method will not work in any Android ICS and above versions phones. Useless fellow Google has removed the very excellent feature from ICS and above versions.